# Colon (:) before pyspark.sql 'pandas_udf()' function?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In the documentation for apply() from the pyspark.sql module, code was provided that contained a colon before the function 'pandas_udf()'.  What does that mean, and why was it included?  I get syntax errors trying to run the line.  Code from the documentation is below.

Here is a [link to the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf).

Running the code gave me a syntax error, obviously.  Also tried removing the colon, but no luck.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))
:pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)  # doctest: +SKIP
def normalize(pdf):
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std())`enter code here`
df.groupby("id").apply(normalize).show()  # doctest: +SKIP
```

Comment: I think that's an error in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in the documentaiton. `pandas_udf` is meant to be used as a decorator, therefore it should be preceded by `@` instead of `:`.

This example should work :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

# Use pandas_udf to define a Pandas UDF
@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
# Input/output are both a pandas.Series of doubles

def pandas_plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

df.withColumn('v2', pandas_plus_one(df.v))
```